# Displaying a JPG in WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I known this question has been done to death but ive read all the answers and its just not working for me.

Image1.jpg & Image2.jpg is added into my project as a "Build Action" of Resource. 
My project is a class library.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PanningMode="Both">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" CanHorizontallyScroll="True">
            <Image Name="Image1" Source="pack://application:,,,/Views/Icons/Image1.jpg" Visibility="Visible" />
            <Image Name="Image2" Source="pack://application:,,,/Views/Icons/Image2.jpg" Visibility="Visible" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Nothing is displaying on the Window.

**UPDATE:**

I had a look through the control with Snoop and there are some strange things.

The Image Source property shows as being empty in Snoop even though its clearly set in the XAML. 
The height and width are zero.

If i specifically set the height and width then snoop shows this however its still not showing.

The designer correctly shows the image. It just doesnt display at runtime.

Comment: What happens when you set the `Width` and `Height`of the `Image`s to a fixed value? (Or Check in the `LiveVisualTree` if the `Image` `Size` is bigger than 0) And maybe a MCVE would be very helpful.

Comment: *"Nothing is displaying"* - it's too early to give up. *Snoop* the layout, check "Output" window for errors, try to use another image, another path, etc.

Comment: @Sinatr I have done all of that to no avail.

Comment: @LittleBit, By default Image takes Width and Height property of the original image from file. So this can't be a problem

Comment: I tried your code, seems like another `Uri` issue, using `Source="Image1.jpg"` works. Check [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).

Comment: @Polly I'm curious if a (derived)`Panel` which contains the `Image`s has an unexpected Size (I once hid accidentally an element this way).

Comment: @Sinatr I tried with just the file name. It didnt work. Why is snoop not showing the source that i have entered in XAML?

Comment: Does the URI-Format `/Assembly_Name;component/Views/Icons/Image1.jpg` work?

Comment: @LittleBit. Yes it does. Thanks. Anyone know why the other methods dont?

Comment: Because everything runs in the context of the exe. Relative paths are relative to that.

Comment: When the image files are resources in a referenced assembly, you have to add that assembly name (and `;component/`) to the Pack URI.